# set array values into checkbox in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set array vlaues as checked in checkbox using  jquery
I have three values in one array and want to set as checked value of checkbox.

Comment: Are you trying to ask how to set the `value` property of three checkboxes to the values from an array?

Comment: No, I have arraye with 3 values and already have checkboxes qith 10 values.I want to make checked those values which matches with my array values.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/41etxeyy/1/

```js
var arr = [2,5,6];

for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
 $('input[type="checkbox"][value="' + arr[i] +'"]').prop('checked', 'checked');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1" />1 <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="2" />2 <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="3" />3 <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="4" />4 <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="5" />5 <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="6" />6 <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="7" />7 <br/>
```

I guess this is what you are looking for.